# how to give firebase database collection item a unique ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have my code set up like this

```
const userCollectionRef = collection(db, 'users');
```

and then I create the data like this :

```
const addInfoToDataBase = async () => {
    checkLike();
    await addDoc(userCollectionRef, {
      likePost: userLikes,
      username: user,
      id: sale_id,
    });
  };
```

The way this is setup it generates users> *random assigned id value* > {id, username, likepost}

I'm trying to change that random assigned id value and assign it a dynamic item that I have called **sale_Id**. I tried doing this :

```
const userCollectionRef = collection(db, 'users', sale_id, 'id');
```

but this creates users> *sale_id* > id > *random assigned id value* > {id, username, likepost}

Is it possible to achieve users> *sale_id* > {id, username, likepost} ?

Comment: You'll want to use `setDoc` to specify an identifier. See [Add data to Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `setDoc` for your use-case. See code below:

```
import { doc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore"; 

// Adds a new document in the collection "users" which uses `sale_id` as document id.
await setDoc(doc(db, "users", sale_id), {
  id: sale_id,
  username: user,
  likePost: userLikes
});
```

For more information, you may check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document).